# slow pppoe connection using Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

```
I have a Compaq Presario CQ61, instaled Ubuntu 9.10 and Windows 7 on it.
```

It works great except the PPPoE connection in Ubuntu, when i dial in Windows my download speed reach up to 91 Mb, rebooted in Ubuntu, downloaded same file from the same server with a speed of maximum 3 Mb, cheked in Windows again 80 - 90 Mb constant. I can't figure what slow's the internet connection in Ubuntu.

Anyone has an ideea on this problem ?

(NO iptables configured, NO HTB, CBQ ...etc configured) .

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I don't have any modem or router. I am using PPPoE directly from my PC.
I didn't mentioned that I instaled Ubuntu two times but didn't figured out what was causing the problem, so I instaled Fedora 12 (64), this works fine and the speed reached 85 Mb.
I **instaled latest Ubuntu 10.4** on the same Laptop, the problem is not solved, the speed reaches up to 3Mb, when in Windows or Fedora reaches up to 95 Mb (yesterday).

Anyone has any ideas on what should I do ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :)

**I changed the driver of my ethernet from r8169 to r8101 ( download from [here](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=7&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) ).**

Now I downloaded the same file from the same server with 76 Mb ( maybe the server is a little overloaded now :) , but the difference from 3 to 76 is huge ).

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, what type of broadband are you using? Cable? Satelite? Fiber? Any reason why you aren't letting your modem/router handle the PPPoE handshake?

Comment: This should be a comment, imho.

Comment: upgraded the question with an answer to your question. :)